# Why does POST gets interpreted as GET?

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up basic routing with a submit form.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/names">
   <input name="name"></input>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
class Router {
    public $routes = [
        'GET' => [],
        'POST' => []
    ];

    public function get($uri, $controller){
        $this->routes['GET'][$uri] = $controller;
    }

    public function post($uri, $controller){
        $this->routes['POST'][$uri] = $controller;
    }

    public function direct($uri, $requestType){
        if(array_key_exists($uri, $this->routes[$requestType])){
            return $this->routes[$requestType][$uri];
        }

        throw new Exception('No route defined for this uri');   
    }
}

$router = new Router;

$router->get('', 'index.view.php');
$router->post('names', 'add-name.php');

class Request {
    public static function uri(){
        return trim(
            parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH),'/'
        );
    }

    public static function method(){
        return $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    }
}

require $router->direct(Request::uri(), Request::method());
```

But every time I submit it just says "no route defined for this uri" And I think the problem is that the POST request gets interpreted as GET. When I try

```
var_dump(Request::uri());
var_dump(Request::method());
```

It says string(5) "names" string(3) "GET"

I'm really confused why this is happening. Any ideas why POST switches to GET?

Comment: FYI: You are missing the `type` property on your input.

Comment: Could it be that `action="/names"` yet the route is `$router->post('names', 'add-name.php');`?

Comment: I don't know, I tried switching to action="/add-name.php"> but same problem

Comment: You missed my point, you are registering a route for the URL `names` but your form is pointing to `/names`. Notice the forward slash.

Comment: So what would be my best bet? I tried removing action entirely and just using the php routing, but it still registers as GET when I submit the form

Comment: @MagdiGamal Ok, I presume since when the form is submitted, request tries to go to `http://some_domain_url/names`, but as I can see, your `Router` class is centre for all requests. So, have you achieved this using `.htaccess` or something? If so, then since this redirection always happens, request stays as `GET` instead of `POST`.